# NavigationBar not showing after picking image from album

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, photo-gallery

I have button for picking image from photo album. After picking image, i need to show navigationBar and share button. But navigationBar is not showing after picking image. I used `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];. But navigation bar not showing.

code:

```
-(void)showAlbum:(id)sender{

    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    //release picker
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    //set image

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];

   newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [newImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

[self.view addSubview:newImage];

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide navigation bar after `dismissModalViewController`

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    //set image

   newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [newImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

[self.view addSubview:newImage];

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Or put this in `viewWillAppear`, because this will call after `dismiss` your `ModalViewController`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the View where you are presenting the ImagePicker Controller , Please add

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

in the `ViewWillAppear` Method. I think that may be the issue. Please update me on the latest.